# How to merge two maps into one with keys from the first map and merged values?

Tags: scala

How can I create a new map from two maps of maps so that the resulting map only includes matches where keys are the same and combines the internal maps.

```
Iterable[Map[String, Map[String,Float]]
```

Example:

```
val map1 = Iterable(Map(
  1 -> Map(key1 -> val1), 
  2 -> Map(key2 -> val2), 
  3 -> Map(key3 -> val3)
))

val map2 = Iterable(Map(
  1 -> Map(key11 -> val11), 
  3 -> Map(key33 -> val33), 
  4 -> Map(key44 -> val44), 
  5 -> Map(key55 -> val55)
))
```

I want the resulting map be as follows:

```
Map(
  1 -> Map(key1 -> val1, key11 -> val11), 
  3 -> Map(key3 -> val3, key33 -> val33)
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update: I don't really understand what your edit about `Iterable`s means, or the error in your comment, but here's a complete working example with `String`s and `Float`s:

```
val map1: Map[Int, Map[String, Float]] = Map(
  1 -> Map("key1" -> 1.0F),
  2 -> Map("key2" -> 2.0F),
  3 -> Map("key3" -> 3.0F))

val map2: Map[Int, Map[String, Float]] = Map(
  1 -> Map("key11" -> 11.0F),
  3 -> Map("key33" -> 33.0F), 
  4 -> Map("key44" -> 44.0F),      
  5 -> Map("key55" -> 55.0F))

val map3: Map[Int, Map[String, Float]] = for {
  (k, v1) <- map1
  v2 <- map2.get(k)
} yield (k, v1 ++ v2)
```

Update in response to your question below: it doesn't make a lot of sense to have a list of maps, each containing a single mapping. You can very easily combine them into a single map using `reduceLeft`:

```
val maps = List(
  Map(1216 -> Map("key1" -> 144.0F)),
  Map(1254 -> Map("key2" -> 144.0F)),
  Map(1359 -> Map("key3" -> 144.0F))
)

val bigMap = maps.reduceLeft(_ ++ _)
```

Now you have one big map of integers to maps of strings to floats, which you can plug into my answer above.

Comment: i got the following error when trying to use this constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : (T1, T2) required: 
 scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.Float]]

Comment: The issue is may map1 and map2 are returned to me like this: val Iterable[Map[Int, Map[String, Float]]]

Comment: Are you sure there's always (and only) one map in the `Iterable`? Then just take the `head`.

Comment: No the data looks like this: List(Map(1216 -> Map(key -> 144.0)), Map(1254 -> Map(key -> 144.0)), Map(1359 -> Map(key -> 144.0))

Comment: I gave this to you because on my original question you were right.  I will create a new question based on what I really am looking for.

Answer (score 6):

```
val keys = map1.keySet & map2.keySet
val map3 = keys.map(k => k -> (map1(k) ++ map2(k)))
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized that my returning maps are of type iterable.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing with something similar to convert a `Seq(Map("one" -> 1), Map("two" -> 2))` to `Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2)`.

I have been looking at previous answers and thought it was too difficult. After playing a bit I found that this solution works and it easy:

```
val seqOfMaps = Seq(Map("one" -> 1), Map("two" -> 2))
seqOfMaps: Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = List(Map(one -> 1), Map(two -> 2))

val allInOneMap = seqOfMaps.flatten.toMap
allInOneMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(one -> 1, two -> 2)
```

The advantage of this approach is that possible empty maps automatically get filtered out.