# Converting a list of Maps to a single map in scala

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala How to create a new map from two other maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641102/scala-how-to-create-a-new-map-from-two-other-maps)

I have the following list of maps that I need to convert to a single map.  What is the best way to do this?

The list of maps are of type:

```
Iterable[Map[String, Map[String,Float]]
```

Example:

```
val list1 = List(Map(1216 -> Map(key1 -> 144.0)), 
     Map(1253 -> Map(key1 -> 144.0)), 
     Map(1359 -> Map(key1 -> 144.0))

val list2 = List(Map(1216 -> Map(key2 -> 148.0)), 
     Map(1200 -> Map(key2 -> 144.0)), 
     Map(1359 -> Map(key2 -> 144.0))
```

I want a resulting map that would be

```
val map3 = Map(
        1216 -> Map(key1 -> 1440, key2 -> 148.0), 
        1359 -> Map(key1 -> 1440, key2 -> 144.0))
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, find all the keys that should be in your new map, which are keys that exist in both of your lists of maps (I'm assuming):

```
val keys = list1.map(_.keySet).reduceLeft(_ | _) & list2.map(_.keySet).reduceLeft(_ | _)
```

Then pick out the values of all of those keys:

```
val alllist = list1 ++ list2
val map3 = keys.map(k => k -> alllist.flatMap(_ get k).reduceLeft(_ ++ _))
```

Not super-efficient, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, something like this will do the trick:

```
scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala> import Scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> list1 ++ list2
res2: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Double]]] = List(Map(1216 -> Map(key1 -> 144.0)), Map(1253 -> Map(key1 -> 144.0)), Map(1359 -> Map(key1 -> 144.0)), Map(1216 -> Map(key2 -> 148.0)), Map(1200 -> Map(key2 -> 144.0)), Map(1359 -> Map(key2 -> 144.0)))


scala> .foldLeft(Map[Int,Seq[Map[String,Double]]]()) { case (acc, v) => 
     | v.mapValues(Seq(_)) |+| acc
     | }
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Seq[Map[String,Double]]] = Map(1216 -> List(Map(key2 -> 148.0), Map(key1 -> 144.0)), 1253 -> List(Map(key1 -> 144.0)), 1359 -> List(Map(key2 -> 144.0), Map(key1 -> 144.0)), 1200 -> List(Map(key2 -> 144.0)))


scala> .map { case(i, m) => (i, m reduce (_ ++ _)) }
res11: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Map[String,Double]] = Map(1216 -> Map(key2 -> 148.0, key1 -> 144.0), 1253 -> Map(key1 -> 144.0), 1359 -> Map(key2 -> 144.0, key1 -> 144.0), 1200 -> Map(key2 -> 144.0))y2 -> 148.0)), Map(1200 -> Map(key2 -> 144.0)), Map(1359 -> Map(key2 -> 144.0)))
```